# Is 106volts and 109volts too coming from transformer?

Tags: electrical

My main legs coming from my transformer reading 106 and the other one reading 109 instead of the 110 that's supposed to be would that make my water pump not come on?

Comment: It is low, but the pump should come on, won't work well but come on.  120 is suppose to be the target standard plus/minus a few volts.  If you get those reading day and night then something is wrong(maybe if a factory next door started up in the morning).  Have your local power company come and check their equipment.

Comment: it should read 110 without any load connected. If the transformer is under sized the Voltage will drop when you draw current.

Comment: what transformer is it anyway ? what for ? transforming from what to what ?

Comment: Should add what region/country you are, to your question.  I am assuming North America.

Comment: Where are you that your voltage is 110V?  "America but literally everyone calls it 110V" they also call a photocopy a Xerox.  In 1915 when they first started selling electrical hookups to houses in cities, the power was 110. The name stuck.  Power is 120 now in North America.  110 would be *really low* lol.

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume it is an Isolation transformer you are talking about, since there is no other reason to have transformer to the water pump.

The isolation transformer as the name says are used for added on safety.

Separating main power from the output power.

If your Isolation transformer is under rated (the output power to low) the pump will not run and you will see Voltage drop on the outlets.

Let's check the water pump numbers, Voltage = 120, Current = ?? Amps ?

The isolation transformer should also have the numbers, sometimes in Watts or kWatts)

Let's say the water pumps says 120 V and 5 Amp. = 600 Watts.

The transformed needs to be that or more (like 1,000 watts)

If the load on the transformer output site exceeds the Transformer specs, you will see a Voltage drop and not enough current to run the pump.

There are also step-up and step-down transformers, used to adjust the voltage to the need. I assume that is not the case here., but if it is, same requirement applies. They have to have enough power (Watts) to drive the pump.